# NGINX redirect results in "DisallowedHost at /"

Tags: nginx, centos, 301-redirect

I have installed nginx on a CentOS 7 box at Azure, and I have configured it like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywhateverdomain.com;
    return 301 www.mywhateverdomain.com.br$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mywhateverdomain.com.br;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

But whenever I try to access `http://mywhateverdomain.com` from a web browser, I get the following message:

```
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'mywhateverdomain.com.br'. You may need to add u'mywhateverdomain.com.br' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Searching around I found a lot of resources talking about Django and about updating the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in the `settings.py` file, but the problem is that I don't use Django, nor there is a `settings.py` in my Linux distro (so far).

Accessing `http://www.mywhateverdomain.com` from a web browser works just fine.

This is the traceback exposed in the browser:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://mywhateverdomain.com.br/

Django Version: 1.10.6
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('django_cleanup',
 'website.apps.VideoConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')

Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  244.             response = middleware_method(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  57.         host = request.get_host()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/request.py" in get_host
  113.             raise DisallowedHost(msg)

Exception Type: DisallowedHost at /
Exception Value: Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'mywhateverdomain.com.br'. You may need to add u'mywhateverdomain.com.br' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

By the way, there is no `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/` directory in my CentOS and not `common.py`, `request.py`, and so on files. What could be the problem here??

Comment: You've missed `http://` in `return`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, I have tested with and without `http://`. Right now it is with `http://`, but it is not working.

Comment: Probably your browser cached wrong redirect.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, no, the cache is not the problem, I try to access `http//mywhate...` url from a browser that I have never used before, and it still doesn't work.